# bash: Cancelling the execution of 'trap handler DEBUG'

Tags: bash, debugging, trap

I can get a function `myHandler()` to execute before a `bash` command by doing the following:

```
function myHandler() {
   ...
}
trap 'myHandler' DEBUG
```

However, I'd like to be able to proceed with or abort the execution of the impending `BASH_COMMAND` based on a runtime condition within `myHandler` as follows:

```
function myHandler() {
   if ! myCondition ; then
      abort the execution of BASH_COMMAND right here
   fi
   # Proceed with the execution of BASH_COMMAND
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, just enable `extdebug` and return a non-zero code ([See the description of `extdebug` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin-1)) from `myHandler`:

```
$ function myHandler() {
  if [[ $SKIP = "true" ]]; then return 1; fi;
  echo 'myHandler execute'
}
$ trap 'myHandler' DEBUG
$ shopt -s extdebug
$ echo 1
myHandler execute
1
$ SKIP=true
myHandler execute
$ echo 1
```