# I'm trying to prevent the execution of a command in BASH.. Doesn't work always

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

This is based on [another question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638367/shopt-s-extdebug-in-bashrc-not-working-in-script-files) I am trying to prevent executions of certain commands using a script. I got the script to work perfectly in interactive shells but for non interactive shells it doesn't prevent its execution. I [did see this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285669/bash-cancelling-the-execution-of-trap-handler-debug) and I am doing the same thing.

/home/user/stop.sh (sourced in .bashrc)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extdebug; stop_cmd () {
    [ -n "$COMP_LINE" ] && return  # not needed for completion
    [ "$BASH_COMMAND" = "$PROMPT_COMMAND" ] && return # not needed for prompt
    local this_command=$BASH_COMMAND;
    echo $this_command" Not Allowed";
    return 1
};
trap 'stop_cmd' DEBUG
```

/home/user/temp.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ls
```

I used the BASH_ENV variable suggested by [@Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian) to get my script into script files that use non-interactive shells.

In a new shell

```
#:export BASH_ENV=/home/user/stop.sh
#:ls
ls Not Allowed --> This is because of the source in .bashrc
#:             --> Prompt appears. ls did not run
#:./temp.sh
./temp.sh: /usr/share/bashdb/bashdb-main.inc: No such file or directory
./temp.sh: warning: cannot start debugger; debugging mode disabled
ls Not Allowed  --> Because of the $BASH_ENV
Directory contents displayed  --> ls ended up running
#:             --> Prompt appears after executing temp.sh
```

But this behavior is not displayed if I source stop.sh within temp.sh directly and it works like a charm.

Comment: Please don't [crosspost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48672149/im-trying-to-prevent-the-execution-of-a-command-in-bash-doesnt-work-always).

Comment: @chepner Sorry about that. I started off there... But I saw that there was a similar effort answered here and hence I linked them

Comment: whoever downvoted this great job! I cant seem to get answers anywhere. Thanks for making it worse.

Comment: Can you run your script with `bash -i`?

Comment: @cuonglm Well I would.. But i can't expect people who make scripts to do that. And that's why I am trying to do this. Thank you for reading my email :)

Comment: @cuonglm There must be some way that I can achieve what I want to do without getting end users to do things line bash -i,  If it works for interactive shells... why not non-interactive... what is this special behavior with regards to return values..

Comment: Made question as an example driven one.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not possible to restrict command execution with the DEBUG trap within non-interactive shell.

Alternatively you can try different approaches:

### Restriction with rbash, BASH_ENV and command_not_found_handle

- Setup a test user
- Symlink the allowed commands within test-users
  homedir

example:

```
allow=(bash cat sed)
user="ruser"
homedir="/home/$user"
mkdir "$homedir/bin"
for c in ${allow[@]}; do
  ln -s /bin/$c $homedir/bin
done
```

- Set the `PATH` variable in `/home/$user/.bashenvrc` and ensure that it only lists bindirs you want to allow, for example `/home/$user/bin;...;...`
- Set `BASH_ENV=/home/$user/.bashenvrc` from `/home/$user/.bashrc`
- Use a restricted shell via `bash -r` so the user cannot execute command names containing slashes, for example `/bin/sh`.

But keep the [rbash security weaknesses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell) in mind.

You want more fine grained restriction possibilities? You could extend this method with the `command_not_found_handle ()` function, so every command which is not found in `PATH` can be handled in detail.

```
function command_not_found_handle () {
  while read -r pattern; do
    [[ "$1" =~ $pattern ]] \
    && command="/bin/restrict/$1" \
    && [ -h $command -a -x $command ] \
    && shift \
    && { $command "$@"; return $?; }
  done </bin/restrict/whitelist
  echo "Command '$1' not found."
}
```

### Restriction with rbash, blacklist and wrappers

- Setup a blacklist as root

example:

```
cat <<EOF >/home/cmd_blacklist
  ~/bin/ls -al
  ~/bin/rm -rf
EOF
chmod g-wx+r,o-wx+r /home/cmd_blacklist
```

- Add `BASH_ENV=~/.bashenvrc` to `~/.bashrc`
- Edit `~/.bashenvrc`

example:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin"
errmsg='arguments not allowed: $cmd $pattern'
while read -r cmd pattern; do
  [ ! -e "$cmd" ] && continue # skip nonexistent
  [ "$cmd" == "$(basename $cmd)" ] && continue  # prevent recursion
  eval "function $(basename $cmd) () { [[ \"$(printf $'%s ' \$@)\" =~ $pattern ]] && echo \"$errmsg\" || $cmd \"\$@\"; }"
done </home/cmd_blacklist
```

Now every line of blacklist of the form [cmd] [pattern] should be read, from which wrapper functions are generated. You could also [export the wrapper functions to subshell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22796/can-i-export-functions-in-bash)

### Further reading and straightforward method with sudo

For many cases [editing the sudoers configuration to restrict command execution](https://superuser.com/questions/167631/fine-grained-sudoers-configuration-allowed-commandline-arguments) is the best choice.

Comment: Well I thought of that already.. moreover If I was to take this approach I would just add users to groups who can run this script right... but my requirement is more fine grained.. for eg: if some one runs ls I will permit it. But if some one runs ls -al I don’t want to.. for this I need to study the entire command carefully and compare against a text file that have certain rules... and hence the need for this.. I hope some one can answer this

Comment: But in my above comment ls will be in PATH i just dont want ls -al to be run (running ls by itself is fine)..  Using the edited approach will I not be force to have an empty PATH so that every command goes through this handle? Also I do not want to give them a notion that command is not present in PATH.  A person could easily install ls into that PATH.